# Bootstrap4 - Splitting the Row into two columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to split a row into two so that I can accommodate two headings in a row, something like below:
[image]

With the current code that I have written, I am unable to separate the row into two like the above and also unable to maintain the responsiveness like below:
[image]

Below is the output that I am getting with the current code:
[image]

Below here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid mail-body" style="width: 740px;">
<div id="account" class="row your-account">
  <div class="col text-right" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; color:#004990; text-decoration:none; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px;">
    Your Account
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.your-account -->

<div id="logo" class="row">
  <div class="col text-center" style="background-color:#0471AF; height:100px; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    LOGO
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.logo -->

<div id="order-text" class="row">
  <div class="col text-center" style="min-height: 98px; vertical-align:middle; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:36px; color: #0471AF; font-weight:100; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <span style="align-self: center;">Heading Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.order-text -->

<div class="row">
  <div id="left-side-text" class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" style=" line-height: 18px;">
    <span style="vertical-align:top; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color: #333333; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; line-height: 18px; font-weight:100;">
      Dear XYZ,
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:17px; text-decoration: none; text-align:left;  padding-bottom:20px;">Good news! Your order is confirmed.</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span style="vertical-align:top; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color: #333333; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; font-weight:100;">
      Some other text
    </span>
  </div>
  <!-- /.left-side text -->

  <div id="order-information" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 order-2">
    <div class="col" style="height: 43px; vertical-align:middle; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color: #333333; text-decoration: none; font-weight:700; background: #f2f2f2; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #999999; border-bottom: none;">
      Order Details
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color: #333333; padding: 10px; height: 73px; border: 1px solid #999999; border-top: none;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-2 font-weight-bold" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0">Order Date:</td>
          <td class="col-2" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0">03/06/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-2  font-weight-bold" style="padding: 0px;">Order #:</td>
          <td class="col-2" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0">123456789</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.order-information -->

  <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12" style="line-height: 18px; vertical-align:top; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color: #333333; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; font-weight:100;">
        <br>
        <br>Text1
        <br>
        <br> Text
        <br> Text
      </div>

</div>

<div id="confirmation-email" class="row order-1">
  <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12" style="line-height: 18px; vertical-align:top; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color: #333333; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; font-weight:100;">
    <br>
    <br>Text1
    <br>
    <br> Text
    <br> Text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" >
    <div class="col" style="height: 36px; vertical-align:middle; font-size: 12px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  color: #333333; text-decoration: none; font-weight:700; background: #f2f2f2; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #999999; border-bottom: none;">
      <span class="">Product(s) Ready for Pickup</span>
      <span class="text-right">Quantity</span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me with the proper setup of the html as well the bootstrap classes so as to achieve the expected result.
Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you edit your code to just have the HTML that is required for this problem. That way you will find more help, Right now people will just look into your code and walk away..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I have included the whole HTML code so that ppl can have a look at the parent classes as well. Maybe the parent classes that I have setup might be a problem & hence the whole code.

Comment: Why don't you use just split the row into two columns (col-6)?

Comment: Here is super easy/clean code: https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/LOZjWZ
_ if you need further assistance, don't hesitate to knock me_

Comment: @JestinoSam none of the below answers resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

**Here is super easy/clean code:**

```
<div class="row">        
    <div class="col" >
      Product(s) Ready for Pickup
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right" >
      Quantity
    </div>           
</div>
```

**See the preview link:** https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/LOZjWZ

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two columns within your row using the `col-sm-6` (or relevant classes as per the device needs). Assuming you need the row to have **2 columns** for small, Medium, Large devices and **1 column** for extra small devices, Below is my suggestion (Note: I have removed the style rules for better readability).

```
<div class="row col-md-12">        
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" >
      <span class="float-left">Product(s) Ready for Pickup</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" >
      <span class="float-right">Quantity</span>
    </div>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use col-xl-{value} to get columns.
 Bootstrap Grid http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
 <div class="row">   //row

    <div class="col-xs-6" >  //column 1 for extra large screen, use sm for small, md for medium screen
      <span>Product(s) Ready for Pickup</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6" > //column 2
      <span>Quantity</span>
     </div>    

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **col-md-*** class for child element inside the parent **row** class to split the columns for your need.

```
<div class="row">        
  <div class="col-md-9" >
    Product(s) Ready for Pickup
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" >
    Quantity
  </div>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
        <label for="country">Country</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <select id="country" name="country">
          <option value="australia">Australia</option>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="usa">USA</option>
        </select>
      </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:auto"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
        <label for="country">Country</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <select id="country" name="country">
          <option value="australia">Australia</option>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="usa">USA</option>
        </select>
      </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:auto"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```

**This should help**